# Connect an Ionic3 test app with laravel 5.4 API data

Tags: laravel, angular, api, ionic3

Now I try to connect an Ionic3 test app with laravel 5.4 API data.
[Ionic code is click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ER7S.png)

So, my goal is to show list page in Ionic3 app.
But there are nothing to show.
Could you some advice where I modify code?
Thank you in advence.

**Laravel 5.4 API**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Customer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $customer = Customer::all();    
        return response()->json($customer);
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'=>'required',
            'email' =>'required',
            'tel' =>'required',
        ]);

        $customer = Customer::create($request->all());

        return response()->json($customer);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $customer = Customer::find($id);    
        return response()->json($customer);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $customer = new Customer;
        $customer->name = $request->input('name');
        $customer->email = $request->input('email');
        $customer->tel = $request->input('tel');
        $customer->address = $request->input('address');
        $customer->note = $request->input('note');
        $customer->save();
        return response()->json($customer);
    }    

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $customer = Customer::find($id);
        $customer->delete();    
        return response()->json($customer);
    }
}
```